# MapBox for iOS, custom style

Tags: ios, dictionary, styles, mapbox

I created new map style with Mapbox Studio, then I uploaded it to my account (so I see it in styles tab), then I added StyleID to my iOS MGLMapView
but when I run app it throws error

```
[ERROR] {Map}[Setup]: loading style failed: HTTP status code 404
```

If I don’t use my style, map is working correctly.

Comment: Was anyone able to figure out this issue?

Comment: This is frustrating. I was under the impression you could style your own map, upload it to your account, and then pull it into an app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in viewDidload:

```
mapView.styleURL = NSURL(string: "asset://styles/dark-v7.json")
```

Update 1:

For this moment it is not possible to use custom map style with Mapbox GL for iOS.

['First steps with Mapbox GL for iOS'](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/first-steps-gl-ios/):

***Changing the map style***

*At the moment, Mapbox GL comes bundled with a handful of map styles. That’ll all change in a few months, but for now let’s change the map style to Mapbox Dark...*

Comment: Seems, you need to wait : 
"At the moment, Mapbox GL comes bundled with a handful of map styles. That’ll all change in a few months, but for now let’s change the map style to Mapbox Dark"

[source](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/first-steps-gl-ios/)

Comment: I see; would you recommend using the previous obj-C versions of Mapbox, I ask because the custom style is somewhat a deal breaker and the option to wait a few months would not fly well with the client

Comment: Sorry @kdgwill,  but I don't have an experience with old MapBox SDK for iOS. I  switched a few weeks ago from MapKit to MapBox due designer new point of view in our app, but fortunately, the "dark-v7" that what he wants. Try to contact with MapBox team about custom styles availability for iOS.

Comment: "Very soon, you’ll be able to easily create your own custom GL styles and have them hosted by Mapbox. _In the meantime, it’s necessary to edit styles by hand, following the GL Style Spec. Our GL styles can be shared between native apps and Mapbox GL JS web apps._ See the bundled styles for examples of how to get started and of powerful dynamic styling techniques." Anyone have any idea how to do this? I've adjusted the CSS in Mapbox Studio but how can it be done so in app?